# Prompt for confirmation before executing "git reset --hard"

Tags: git

Unstaged, uncommitted changes are lost after running "git reset --hard HEAD". Can I configure git to ask for confirmation before running this (potentially destructive) command?

Comment: "Doctor, when I use sharp knife I easily cut myself. What do I do?" - "How about NOT using sharp knife?"

Comment: I need this command several times per day. Is there an alternate workflow in which every change is worthy of a commit?

Comment: You should revist your workflow instead of rewriting git. For example by creating local branches (forked) so you can commit a lot and often without risking to break the main tree. Same amount of thinking before pressing "enter" should be performed when you just typed git push

Comment: @Sebastien Thanks, I'll look into branching more frequently.

Comment: What is the scenario in which you find that you need to use `git reset --hard` frequently? What are you trying to achieve when you use it?

Comment: I often use git for python scripts I'm writing. I'll tweak a few parameters and then use git reset --hard if the tweaks aren't worth keeping. At the same time, I often run "python myscript.py; !!; !!; !!; !!...". If I "!!" in the wrong terminal window, I lose my changes.

Comment: Look into git stash and this is definitly a matter of taking the habit of forking branches. Then you replace git reset --hard with git checkout previous_version_branch_name.

Comment: @mvp most accidents with knives happen with dull knives, interestingly enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

put

```
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "rebase" ] && [ "$2" = "--hard" ] && [ "$3" = "HEAD" ] ; then
        echo "are you being a moron again?"
        read i
        if [ "$i" = "no" ]; then
             command git $@
        fi
     fi
}
```

in your `${HOME}/.profile`

Update: while this is one way to solve the problem, I prefer to make a branch backup when I am not entirely confident about the history rewriting operation I'm about to do. I achieve the backup by either force purshing to a WIP branch on remote or using [git-branch-backup](https://github.com/yaccz/git-branch-backup)

Comment: The amount of time that is saved from this due to my stupidity :thumbs_up: